# inject services (Reflector) in createParamDecorator

Tags: dependency-injection, nestjs, decorator, typescript-decorator

I want to have something like

```js
@ProtectResource()
handler(@Resource() resource: ResourceInterface) {
  ...
}
```

Where `@Resource` should have access to `Reflector` and `RemoteService` (provided with the same module as `@Resource`) in order to load all required data:

```js
export const Resource = createParamDecorator(
  async (data: unknown, ctx: ExecutionContext) => {
    // TODO inject Reflector
    const params = reflector.get('protect-uri', ctx.getHandler());

    // TODO inject RemoteService
    return remoteService.load(params.id);
  },
);
```

Unfortunately, I wasn't able to find how I could inject `Reflector` and `RemoteService` in `createParamDecorator` neither in docs nor here.